# How to call close event in ngx-share/button in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have used ngx-share/button package for social share. I need to call API after close social popup / after successfully submit post so how can I get event?

Here is my code of HTML:

```
<a (sbClosed)="closed.emit($event)" sbTitle="Test" sbUrl="http://facebook.com" shareButton="facebook">
```

What should I need to use in component to call event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in component you need to handle closed event ,

```
<child-coponent (closed)="onClosed($event">
</child-component>
```

ts fil

```
onClosed(event) {

}
```

Comment: Can you please help me that how I can share Image via facebook share? I am using             <a (sbClosed)="onClosed($event)" sbImage="image_url" sbTitle="Test" sbUrl="url" shareButton="facebook"> but unable to post image.

Comment: @Milan - not worked on that part ..and not sure i can help you or not

Comment: No Problem. Thanks